# How can i install AMD Catalyst 15.9 Proprietary Ubuntu Graphics Driver

Tags: ati, 64-bit, gpu-driver

Hello could someone navigate me on how to install this driver: http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Ubuntu%20x86%2064

Ubuntu Version: 14.04 lts 64-bit

Gpu: Amd Radeon HD 8850M

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just open the Additional Drivers app (search it in Dash/Start) and use it to install `fglrx`. It's the same driver, but easier to install and update.

If you want to get the driver from the website, just choose the top download option and double click the downloaded `.deb`. `.deb` files are installer packages for Ubuntu.

Comment: Oh it was easier than i thought xD i thought that you had to do all this things you do with the nvidia drivers Thank you!

Comment: @IceDBorn Nvidia also has the same Additional Drivers setup. If this answer is what you were looking for, I'd be really grateful if you clicked that check mark to the left of my answer to mark it as accepted.